# In mysql, is there a way to custom a variable for every connection?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, is there a way to custom a variable for every connection?

Simply, i just wanna use

Set Global myVal = 'xxxxx';

but it doesn't work.

Edited:
More detail:
I just wanna store a part of the encryption key for encrypt the field. so at the php side of my app, it will supply 1/2 part of the key, the key is stored in the php settings , and in mysql, i am going to store the other 1/2 of the encryption key in the mysql setting file or a global variable, so it will be easy to be loaded to every connection.

For example: 
Set Global myKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. In what language?

Comment: I just wanna store a part of the encryption key for encrypt the field. so at the php side of my app, it will supply 1/2 part of the key, the key is stored in the php settings , and in mysql, i am going to store the other 1/2 of the encryption key in the mysql setting file or a global variable, so it will be easy to be loaded to every connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT CONNECTION_ID();
```

to get the current connection ID and either use that directly, or create another variable based on it (perhaps using `CONCAT`).